# How can i check if every HTML tag is closed?

Tags: php, validation, xhtml

i have this problem:

user can add an HTML description and it will be shown on his profile; when i show the user list, i'd wish to show this description, too.
since it could be too long, i'm going to cap it to a fixed lenght, but doing this i could break the HTML syntax leaving some tags open.

how can i check if everthing is ok and, if needed, close any open tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@tampe125 This isn't my code, but it looks like it works.

```
  <?php  /** * close all open xhtml tags at the end of the string

 * * @param string $html

 * @return string

 * @author Milian <mail@mili.de>

 */function closetags($html) {

  #put all opened tags into an array

  preg_match_all('#<([a-z]+)(?: .*)?(?<![/|/ ])>#iU', $html, $result);

  $openedtags = $result[1];   #put all closed tags into an array

  preg_match_all('#</([a-z]+)>#iU', $html, $result);

  $closedtags = $result[1];

  $len_opened = count($openedtags);

  # all tags are closed

  if (count($closedtags) == $len_opened) {

    return $html;

  }

  $openedtags = array_reverse($openedtags);

  # close tags

  for ($i=0; $i < $len_opened; $i++) {

    if (!in_array($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)){

      $html .= '</'.$openedtags[$i].'>';

    } else {

      unset($closedtags[array_search($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)]);    }

  }  return $html;}  ?>
```

Comment: You're welcome, it seems like it will work, although I haven't tried it.  I pulled the answer from http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?343478-Close-all-open-HTML-tags

Comment: Regex is never the right solution, for matching HTML. [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) would probably work better for you.

Comment: @kevinji I know its much later now, but what do you mean regex is never the right solution? Was it a 2011 thing to use libraries instead of vanilla php?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple javascript validator that does basic tag checking.
[XML validator](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)

The only issue is that it will stop at the first error, so you need to work through issues one at a time.